# how to find out why the battery is hot

Tags: performance, progressive-web-apps

Do you have any ideas for finding out why the  phone's battery will be too hot?

I implement the PWA site with React and Firebase (firestore). And I'm running into the above problem. To find out about it, I watch the following tools.

- Chrome's memory tab
- performance's memory tab

Please tell me other ways to find out why the battery is hot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why your phone runs hot and we are unable to deduce which is the main cause with the data provided. But, some reasons why your phone runs hot may be old hardware, deteriorated battery, the cpu consumption of your page is too high, there is a lot of data transfers happening in the background and many more. Sometimes it might not be even your page that is causing your phone to run hot.